# AD domain name migration to a new AD domain

Tags: active-directory

Just want to ask if there is a best way in migrating Active Directory Domain name. Also what is the best first to migrate is it users, workstations, groups or servers?

Really need your help guys.

Thanks,

Comment: Moving objects is the easiest part. The hardest part is updating the profiles on workstations so people can login the next day and have everything working as before. We've use Quest's [Migration Manager](https://www.quest.com/products/migration-manager-for-active-directory/). It is a bit costly (cost is per-user-moved), but it did the job.

Comment: For more info, you might be better off asking at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for questions about server administration. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.